# Could you expand a little on this proof or Floyd-Warshall Algorithm?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I'm reading [this](http://math.mit.edu/~rothvoss/18.304.1PM/Presentations/1-Chandler-18.304lecture1.pdf).

> $\quad$[image]

He gives a proof of Floyd-Warshall's algorithm but I don't understand what he's doing nor why it proves that. I can see an intuitive proof in my mind that is as follows:

- Take one vertex, as the algorithm chooses the outgoing edge with minimum weight and goes to it, if there are edges from $A$ to $B$, then due to the algorithm's nature (picking the edge with minimum weight), this is the shortest path with minimum weight.

I don't know if it's right. I know the proof given is by induction, I just don't really know why induction is necessary in here.

Answer (score 2):

After a quick glance of the linked doc: It seems that the author wants to teach dynamic programming. The approach involves a recursive solution which is then likely to be optimised with memoisation techniques (reuse of once calculated results).

Induction is a natural choice for proving a recursive method, because of its related structure (inductive step = recursion step, induction base case = recursion stop case).